# How do I make items to show in multi select?

Tags: react-native

I'm using following library to select single item from the list where is show company name and email as seen in this image

[image]

My goal is to make it to multi selection but I'm not sure how to. I have been trying this library to make it multi select https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker but none of the items are showing in the list.

This is how the current single select picker component looks like. The offerEmails is coming as router params from the previous screen. This has data as seen in the image above.

```js
            <ModalSelector
              data={offerEmails}
              keyExtractor={(x) => x.id}
              labelExtractor={(x) => x.offer_email}
              initValue={!offerEmail ? 'Sähköposti' : offerEmail}
              initValueTextStyle={{ color: colors.white_087, fontSize: 18 }}
              selectStyle={licensePicker}
              selectTextStyle={{ color: colors.white_087 }}
              cancelStyle={{backgroundColor: colors.red}}
              cancelText="Peruuta"
              cancelTextStyle={{color: colors.white_087, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold'}}
              optionContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: colors.black_021 }}
              onChange={(option) => setOfferEmail(option.offer_email)}
              componentExtractor={(option) => <EmailItem data={option} />}
            />
```

```js
  const EmailItem = ({ data }) => {
    const { optionText } = GlobalStyle
    return (
      <View key={data.id} style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', width: '45%'}}>
        <Text style={optionText}>{data.name}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', width: '55%'}}>
        <Text style={optionText}>{data.offer_email}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

And this is how the current attempt is looking like

```js
        <DropDownPicker
        schema={{
          label: 'company',
          value: 'offer_email'
        }}
          theme='DARK'
          placeholder='Sähköposti'
          multiple={true}
          min={0}
          max={5}
          open={open}
          value={value}
          items={emails}
          setOpen={setOpen}
          setValue={setValue}
          setItems={setEmails}

          mode="BADGE"
          badgeDotColors={["#e76f51", "#00b4d8", "#e9c46a", "#e76f51", "#8ac926", "#00b4d8", "#e9c46a"]}
        />
```

[image]